# UIButton deallocated issue

Tags: ios, memory-management, uibutton

I received this message from the debugger console :

> -[UIButton release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1836b0

But I don't create UIButton programmatically, all my buttons have created in Interface Builder. Each of them are linked to a function, like this :

> -(IBAction)theFunction:(UIButton *)sender;

In lot of this functions, I don't use the variable sender. I don't even try to release it. So I don't understand why my application try to release my buttons.
Do I do something in Interface Builder to release or not my UIButton? Is it about the picture I put in the UIButton? If I use the variable (UIButton *)sender, do I need to release it?
This problem stucks me because of it my application crashes.

Edit:

```
- (IBAction)showPopoverOverview:(UIButton *)sender {
    TouchPlanePopover *content = [[TouchPlanePopover alloc] init];
    [content setTheAlbum:@"Overview"];

    // Setup the popover for use in the detail view.
    detailViewPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
    detailViewPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(600., 400.);
    detailViewPopover.delegate = self;  // Set the sender to a UIButton.

    // Present the popover from the button that was tapped in the detail view.
    [detailViewPopover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    // Set the last button tapped to the current button that was tapped.
    lastTappedButton = sender;
    [content release];
}
```

detailViewPopover is create in .h like this : @property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *detailViewPopover;

Thans for your help
Let me know if you need more information, I will edit the post

Comment: Do you synthesize the buttons?

Comment: I need to synthesize my buttons created in Interface Builder ?

Comment: No, only if you want send messages to them.

Comment: I don't want send message to them, I just want to launch a function when I press a Button.

Comment: where does the crash happen? can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Use debugger to find out where your app crashesh, post that code or line

Comment: what part of stacktrace do you want ? Because it is pretty long...

My app crashes when it receive the message "-[UIButton release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1836b0"

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
-(IBAction)theFunction:(UIButton *)sender
```

to

```
-(IBAction)theFunction:(id)sender
```

Just try...

Comment: In some function, I need to put UIButton

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this and its work properly

So may be its useful for you.

myController.h

#import <\UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class myController;

@interface myController : UIViewController {

}

- (IBAction)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)button;

@end

myController.m

@implementation myController

- (IBAction)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)button {

NSLog(@"work properly");

}

Comment: My functions works, when I press a button it displays what I want